# Why MySQL server shutdown itself

Tags: mysql

I have Whm server, in this server I have many web sites made by python, php, all they use mySQL but sometime my MySQL server shutdown itself, I couldn't understand what is the problem with it, I attached error which server send me. What is the way I can solve this problem, how can I find the error.

[image: error log]

when I look at the error log my last error before MySQL server shutdown is this;

`2015-07-06 07:21:06 22441 [Warning] IP address '118.193.181.51' could not be resolved: Name or service not known`

Comment: What does it say in MySQL's error log?

Comment: I need a **magnifier** . Copy the text here.

Comment: Everything is in the log (open the file in separate window, the picture is big) - you have corrupted database tables, so mysql cannot start. The log suggest to run *WHM's Repair MySQL database*. Have you already done that?

Comment: Also between the `mysqlcheck` lines you probably have names of individual tables which are corrupted.

Comment: How do you conclude that a table is corrupted from "Can't connect to local MySQL server..." ?

Comment: when I open app, it gives MySQL server error and I restart MySQL server,  they start working again so that's why I conclude that table corrupt from it. I'm trying to find the error from error log.

Comment: @Vatev it's the first line of that pictured logfile

Comment: when I look at the error log my last error before MySQL server shutdown is this;
2015-07-06 07:21:06 22441 [Warning] IP address '118.193.181.51' could not be resolved: Name or service not known